# How do I sort a pandas data frame by date time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I have a .csv file that I am reading into a pandas data frame.  The .csv file has the following format

```
Date,Expense
03/05/2015,75.0
01/01/2015,45.0
01/02/2015,245.0
01/02/2015,1280.0
01/02/2015,75.0
01/05/2015,55.0
01/03/2015,287.0
01/07/2015,3185.0
01/07/2015,981.0
01/07/2015,342.0
01/02/2015,64.8
```

I am reading the file in with the following code;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(text_file.csv, sep=',', dtype={'Date': str, 'Expense': float})
```

I then transform `df['Date']` to a date time object via;

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.sort_values(by='Date')
print(df['Date'])
```

When I print the newly sorted data it is obvious that the values were transformed into a date time object, but they are not sorted.  How do I get pandas to sort the dates in chronological order?

```
0  2015-03-05
1  2015-01-01
2  2015-01-02
3  2015-01-02
4  2015-01-02
5  2015-01-05
6  2015-01-03
7  2015-01-07
8  2015-01-07
9  2015-01-07
10 2015-01-02
Name: Date, type: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: You need to re-assign back to df. `sort_value` is not an inplace operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reassign back to df **or** use the `inplace=true` parameter:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

OR

```
df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)

print(df['Date'])
```

Output:

```
1    2015-01-01
2    2015-01-02
3    2015-01-02
4    2015-01-02
10   2015-01-02
6    2015-01-03
5    2015-01-05
7    2015-01-07
8    2015-01-07
9    2015-01-07
0    2015-03-05
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```